# usar corner radius programaticamente en linear, modificando a circuferencia apenas em um lado

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Modifica apenas um lado de uma linear]

usar corner radius programaticamente en um linear, modificando apenas a circuferencia de  ou dois lados

Comment: Certo, mas qual o problema? alguma dúvida? está tendo problemas em conseguir reproduzir no código o que está nas imagens? Seja bem vindo ao SO-PT, não se esqueça de fazer o [tour] e veja também [Como criar um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Crie um `Drawable` para fazer a forma do `corner`, com o nome `corner.xml`, como abaixo:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke 
         android:width="2dp" 
         android:color="#FF0000">
    </stroke>
    <solid 
        android:color="#FFFF00">
    </solid>
    <corners 
         android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
         android:topRightRadius="0dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
         android:bottomRightRadius="0dp">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

Após isso insira o mesmo como background do seu `LinearLayout`, como abaixo:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/corner">
 </LinearLayout>
```